# Can't find the nth root of user input in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I'm trying to calculate the nth root of a user input for a complete calculation of the variable a in an exponential function. I just can't seem to get it to do the math.

Here's my input code, and calculation.

```
input_a = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Please enter the 2 points format x1 x2 y1 y2: ").split()]

a_result = (input_a[3] / input_a[2])**(1.0 / (input_a[1] - input_a[0]))
```

Comment: careful: integer division applies between integers in python 2. `input_a[3] / input_a[2]` should be `input_a[3] / float(input_a[2])`

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Thanks for providing the code snippet. You might get better answers, and get them more quickly, if you provide a short, **complete** program, along with the expected and actual output. Please see [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you're creating a list of integers, then use this computation in your formula:

```
input_a[3] / input_a[2]
```

since you're using python 2 (your code is okay in python 3), you're using *integer division*, and your computation is wrong in that case.

I would do:

```
float(input_a[3]) / input_a[2]
```

or use

```
from __future__ import division
```

or just parse numbers as `float` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. But I still don't get the correct answer. I can't get it to print an answer for me that much higher than 1.

`Please enter the 2 points format x1 x2 y1 y2:  322 452 432 241`
`a is equal to: 1.0`

Comment: in that case, your formula is wrong. Do you know that `**` is 'power' ?

Comment: Yes, I read in another answer on the nth root topic that this would able me to calculate any root of the number.